# Magento 2 assign products to category not always working

Tags: php, magento, magento2, product, categories

First of all, I understand how to programmatically assign products to a category.
However it seems that this is sometimes not working and I cannot find out what the issue is.

```
Magento Version: 2.4.5-p1

PHP version: 8.1
```

**My code**:

```
$categoryLinkRepository = $objManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
$categoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $CategoryIds);
```

*$CategoryIds* is an array containing the categories the product should be assigned to.

I have added an error_log to the core file

***vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkManagement.php***

to check if the category will be assigned. Here the section where my error_log is added (line 101):

```
foreach (array_diff($categoryIds, $assignedCategories) as $categoryId) {
            error_log("Assigning----> SKU: $productSku - CAT: $categoryId");
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface $categoryProductLink */
        $categoryProductLink = $this->productLinkFactory->create();
        $categoryProductLink->setSku($productSku);
        $categoryProductLink->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $categoryProductLink->setPosition(0);
        $this->getCategoryLinkRepository()->save($categoryProductLink);
    }
```

Here the output of the error log:

```
Assigning----> SKU: 83689 - CAT: 1816
```

**Expected behaviour:**

I expect the product **83689** to be assigned to the category **1816** when looking in the **Magento Dashboard > Catalog > Categories**

**Actual behaviour:**

The product is not assigned.

I have looked into the database. Same, the category id 1816 is missing.

```
MariaDB [magentodb]> select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku = '83689';
+-----------+
| entity_id |
+-----------+
|     14427 |
+-----------+


MariaDB [magentodb]> select * from catalog_category_product where product_id = 14427;
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+
| entity_id | category_id | product_id | position |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+
|    183887 |        1742 |      14427 |        0 |
|    183889 |        1785 |      14427 |        0 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Next steps:

I am not sure now how to proceed and solve this issue.
This is happening with a lot of products.
The category is a 3rd level category in the category tree:

```
Default Category
   |
   ---> sub-category
        |
        ----> Category 1816
```

**Questions**:

Is it because the category is 3rd level that it is not assigned properly?
--> but then, why are my logs showing that it is about to be assigned?

What else can I try to troubleshoot the situation?

If I wrap my code (see first section "My code" above) in a try-catch statement no error will be shown. The code is therefore working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

### Update and Solution

The code above is working perfectly fine and there was no issue there. The problem appeared further down in my script in a section which is updating the position of the products inside categories.
To do this I am using the method

`$category->setPostedProducts($positions);`

where `$positions` is an array with Product IDs as index and position (int) as value.

What I didn't know -- **and this might be interesting for others** -- is that if you omit products that are part of the category in this array, **these products will be removed from the category during the repositioning**. I thought they would just have their position set to 0.

The result is that products were at first assigned correctly to the category, but later removed from it during the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

As you can check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/249773) the link management defers the category assignment to the scheduled indexer. If you do `$product->save()` after assignProductToCategories, new assignments are lost.

It's preferable to execute `assignProductToCategories` at the end to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Pachis. Yes, I was aware of this and had the product saved before assigning the category. Please see my update above for the solution. It took me a while to realise that..